# What is the relevance of the definition of a closed submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

In my course on Stochastic Calculus,a closed submartingale was defined

Def:We say that a submartingale $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R_+}}$ is closed by $X_{\infty}$ if there exists a random variable $X_{\infty}$ that is $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}= \sigma(\mathcal{F}_{t},t \geq 0)$ measurable and integrable such that for every t we have $$X_t \leq E[X_{\infty} \vert \mathcal{F_t}] \text{a.s.}$$

I understand the definition which is very clear but I do not get the motivation behind it . If someone could explain it would be really helpful.

Comment: I think it's easier to understand the motivation in the martingale case. If $(X_t)_t$ is a closable martingale, then $$X_t = \mathbb{E}(X_{\infty} \mid \mathcal{F}_t),$$ i.e. we can identity the process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ with a single random variable $X_{\infty}$ (as we can reconstruct $X_t$ from $X_{\infty}$ and $\mathcal{F}_t$). The identity shows for example that any closable martingale is uniformly integrable.